# Getting attributes of a model generated by swagger by using introspection in python

Tags: python, introspection, swagger-editor

I have a model generated by swagger editor and would like to get its attributes by using introspection/reflection and also to find their types. I then would like to do something based on the type of the attributes.

The function that I have written to do this is;

```
def getting_attributes(Model1):
    for name in dir(Model1):
        attr = getattr(Model1,name)
        if not callable(attr):
            print(name,':',attr)


 getting_attributes(test_model)
```

This works fine, but then I am unable to write if else statement to retrieve attr type. 
The models' attributes that I get looks like this;

```
__dict__ : {'swagger_types': {'name': <class 'str'>, 'rdfs_label': <class 'str'>, 'rdfs_comment': <class 'str'>, 'has_a_b_c': typing.List[swagger_server.models.a_b_c.ABC], 'has_d_e_f': typing.List[swagger_server.models.d_e_f.DEF],.......}

'attribute_map': {'name': 'name', 'rdfs_label': 'rdfs.label',
'rdfs_comment': 'rdfs.comment', ....}

'_name': 'Test_model', '_rdfs_label': None, '_rdfs_comment': None,...}
```

When I try to find types of these attributes by doing `print(name,":",type(attr))`, I get most of them as `<class 'NoneType'>`. Any ideas on how to find if attribute is a type list, my model type or python type (i.e. string, integer, date...)?

p.s: I can't do attr.items() as it comes as string.